# Mobile As A web Server HTML

Tags: java, android, html

I am working on a project, in which my android is working as a web server; enter the IP address with a port number and a web interface is open from and user can upload Files to mobile. i want to show some pictures on web interface so that we interface looks good.

**How to give reference of images in draw-able or Raw or assets folder in image src"" fiels**

here is my code:

```
     private String getZipLink(long folderId) {
     return "<a href=\"/zip/" + folderId + "/folder.zip\"><img src=\"file:///android_res/raw/img\" />" +
     "Zip of Entire Folder</a>";
```

How to add image there ?
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can embed the image data in your HTML (instead of trying to provide a link to the image data): see [Inline Images with Data URLs](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/).

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the request handling in your web server, you can use a image URL like

```
<img src="images/myimage.png" ... />
```

and handle the request to the resource `images/myimage.png` by returning a byte stream, with the correct MIME type `image/png`. This is very similar to the code used in Java EE Servlets, so you can search for example code and adapt it to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
   /**
     * This method starts the web server listening to the port 8080
     */
    protected void start() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Secure Web Server is starting up on port 8080");
                try {
                    // Create the secure server socket
                    sss = (SSLServerSocket) sssf.createServerSocket(8080);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                    return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for connection");
                while (isRunning) {
                    try {
                        // Wait for an SSL connection
                        Socket socket = sss.accept();

                        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process pr = rt.exec("lsof -i:"+socket.getPort());
                        System.out.println("Process:::"+pr.getInputStream());

                        InputStream in1 = pr.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in1);
                        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                        String read = br.readLine();

                        while(read != null) {
                            //System.out.println(read);
                            sb.append(read);
                            read =br.readLine();

                        }

                        System.out.println("Process read:::"+sb.toString());

                        // Got a connection
                        Log.d(TAG, "Connected, sending data.");

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream());

                        // Read the data until a blank line is reached which
                        // signifies the end of the client HTTP headers
                        String str = ".";
                        while (!str.equals(""))
                            str = in.readLine();

                        // Send a HTTP response
                        out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                        out.println("Server: Android KeyChainiDemo SSL Server");
                        // this blank line signals the end of the headers
                        out.println("");
                        // Send the HTML page
                        out.println("<H1>Welcome to Android!</H1>");
                        // Add an embedded Android image
                        out.println("<img src='data:image/png;base64," + base64Image + "'/>");
                        out.flush();
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }





base64Image = createBase64Image(ctx);


 /**
     * This method reads a binary image from the assets folder and returns the
     * base64 encoded image string.
     *
     * @param ctx The service this web server is running in.
     * @return String The base64 encoded image string or "" if there is an
     *         exception
     */
    private String createBase64Image(Context ctx) {
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(ctx.getAssets().open(**image file stored in assets folder **));
            byte[] embeddedImage = new byte[bis.available()];
            bis.read(embeddedImage);
            return Base64.encodeToString(embeddedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

So place your image in assets folder of android

For more clarification see the KeyChainDemo in android APIDemos in Android samples for Android4.0